# Hosting WCF Service in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, wcf-rest

I'm trying to host a WCF service inside a WPF application but I'm unable to do so.

Here is the code I implemented:

```
ServiceHost host = null;
using (host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.apiService)))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.IApiService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:3300/api/endpoint1");
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.IApiService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:3300/api/endpoint2");
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.IApiService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:3300/api/endpoint3");

host.Open();
```

Everything looks ok and runs fine but the service does not start.

Anyone have an idea of what my problem may be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?   Are any errors thrown?  Is there anything in the event viewer?

Comment: Yes and everything creates fine but when I try connect (using Advanced REST Client) I get an error as if the service isn't running

Comment: From your posted code, it looks like you're hosting a SOAP service - REST is different than SOAP.  Have you tried using `WebHttpBinding` instead of `WSHttpBinding`?

Comment: I actually had basicHttpBinding before, I was trying a couple of different things and that how I ended up with WSHttpBinding....but yes you are right in that I should have used WebHttpBinding....Still no joy though.

Comment: I edited my question to include WebHttpBinding

Comment: It might be due to your `using` block - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely issue is that you've wrapped the creation and opening of the `ServiceHost` in a `using` statement.   Once that `using` statement finishes (and it's not clear from your posted code where it does), the `ServiceHost` instance will be closed.

In other words, if you close the `using` block right after `host.Open();` like this:

```
using (host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.apiService)))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.IApiService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:3300/api/endpoint1");
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.IApiService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:3300/api/endpoint2");
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WcfJsonTransferRestService.IApiService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:3300/api/endpoint3");

    host.Open();
}
```

The host will be closed and your application will not be able to receive requests.   Generally you'll want to open the host on application start (or perhaps on a given event), and then close it once the application exits.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I don't know how I missed it!

Comment: I think several of the samples have the using in, which gets copied over to peoples code.